# XCode truncating validation warning messages

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, app-store

When validating my iOS app inside Xcode 5.0, I get truncated warning messages:

[image: validation errors]

Clicking on these warnings does not give me a full warning message. Is there a way to see the complete warnings?

Comment: These warnings should also be mentioned in the project navigation tab, along with the other warnings.

Comment: I can see other warnings during the build process, but these specific warnings (especially the local thing) only show up after doing online validation of the app.